# python3 sqlite select primary key and insert same value into other table

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, python-3.6

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('animelist2.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
~
~
~
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Production (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE, p_name TEXT)''')

i_production = input('Insert production: ')
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Production (p_name) VALUES (?)''', (i_production))
f_production = cur.execute("SELECT id From Production WHERE p_name = i_production ").fetchone()[0]
~
~
~
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Title (t_name, genre_id, production_id, year_id ) VALUES (?,?,?)''', (i_title, f_genre, f_production, f_year ))
```

sorry I don't know how?what? to name title....(sorry about my bad English)

I brought some parts of my codes an error occurred

when I try this, it says 'no such column: i_production'

I think I can't use this variable 'i_production' at the last line 'f_production = cur.execute("SELECT id From Production WHERE p_name = i_production ").fetchone()[0]'

are there other ways?

I want to select 'production id' primary key and insert same value to other table as a foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending line is the following:

```
f_production = cur.execute("SELECT id From Production WHERE p_name = i_production ").fetchone()[0]
```

I suppose what you want is:

```
f_production = cur.execute("SELECT id From Production WHERE p_name = ?", [i_production]).fetchone()[0]
```